# Spring Creates New Objects But Should Not

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm having the following problem with Spring: I expected that singletons would be created once and then referenced from the Spring cache. But that does not seem to be the case. I have the following lines in my beans.xml:

```
<bean id="Cache" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="singleton" >
</bean>
```

which is referenced below like:

```
<bean id="ManuallyCachingDAO" class="blah"
scope="singleton" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="cache" ref="Cache"></property>
    ...
```

and in the ManuallyCachingDAO the code:

```
public Object get(int id) {
    Object o = cache.get(id);
    if (o != null) {
        return o;
    }
    // ... code for retrieving the object from the DB
}
```

but the `HashMap` gets emptied in mysterious ways sometimes! That is, I don't think it's actually emptied. I think it's just dropped and created anew when I reference the `ManuallyCachingDAO` in another class.

Could you tell me how to fix this problem?

EDIT: At Robin's hint: I do the following to get the beans in a lot of classes (not all though):

```
ClassPathResource blah = etc.; 
XmlBeanFactory xbf = new XmlBeanFactory(blah); 
...
xbf.getBean("Cache");
```

... right now I'm doing it (even for a lot of other beans) ... is that a very stupid or very bad idea or both? I think it occurs to me right now what I'm doing wrong... Until now, I just suspected that all XmlBeanFactories were somehow grabbing the same resources which might have been very dumb indeed, or could s/o tell me what's right?

Comment: please show the init() method

Comment: You should prove that what you think is occurring is ACTUALLY occurring. Either use a debugger or System.out to see if the reference to your "singleton" actually changes. Not knowing for sure, when it's easy to determine, means you may be on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Try checking the hash-code of the map to see if it is the same instance.  There don't appear to be any problems with your config.

Comment: Oh, as a side note. You most probably do NOT want to use a HashMap here. You will get synchronization issues if more than 1 thread is accessing this cache. I would suggest a ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config looks fine, and Spring is well tested in this respect so I don't think there are going to be any surprises there.

Would you by any chance be creating the Spring context each time you are trying to access the beans?  Thereby recreating everything repeatedly.

Comment: You mean I cant't must not do the following in each class: "ClassPathResource blah = etc.; XmlBeanFactory xbf = new XmlBeanFactory(blah); xbf.getBean("Cache");" 
... cause right now I'm doing it ... is that a stupid or bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that Spring is creating new HashMaps. Your configuration looks OK. I am pretty sure something is wrong in your logic.

In the part marked

```
// ... code for retrieving the object from the DB
```

do you actually write the retrieved values to the map?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe concurrency is messing up your map. You don't want to use a HashMap as a singleton since it's not thread safe. Try using [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead.

Comment: +1 for ConcurrentHashMap, although I am sure that's not the cause of the OP's problem

Comment: that's not the problem, but thanks for the hint, thumbs-up from me